# Highest value of float variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two columns with quantity (Float) and serial_no (Int). Now I need to write the model validations for these columns.

For serial_no, I added:

```
  validates_numericality_of :serial_no, {less_than_or_equal_to: 4294967295} #Max Integer value : 2**32 - 1
```

I am bit confused with quantity (float) value. What can be the maximum value for Float variable in Ruby?
I found in few links as

```
340282300000000000000000000000000000000 / 3.402823E+38 / 3.40282347 * 10 ^38.
```

Comment: `Float::MAX # => 1.7976931348623157e+308`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what if I am still on Win32?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: then the constant would return the appropriate value for that platform, I imagine.

Comment: There's also `Float::INFINITY`. `Float::MAX` is only the maximum representable finite value. However it's not 100% clear what you mean by `float`/`Float`. Do you mean the C data type (usually IEEE 754 binary32/single format) or the Ruby class?

Comment: Unless you really don't care about precision, like *at all*, **don't use float**. Use fixed-point types, which in the database are like `DECIMAL(36,18)` for a lot of precision.